# Embedding a side bar in explorer

Tags: embed, explorer, windows-shell, shell-extensions

How do I embed a side bar in explorer like the bar on the right? It's a dropbox-clone in Chinese

[image: example]
After fiddling with SP++, I'm guessing it is finding the HWND, resizing the SHELLDLL_DefView and adding a window to CabinetWClass. Or is there a shell extension that does this? The right window can change depending on the context (which file is selected on the left).

Answer (score 0):

This is **Explorer Bar**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: PS: Do you send me link for this explorer bar? Thanks.